# how to make php add utf8 characters

Tags: php, android, mysql

im trying to add a symbol into the database from my android application .. for example i want to add this A ⊂ B .. this will be saved as A ? B in the database. i tried logging the string in android and its logged correctly so i assumed that the problem is in php right?
also the symbols in the database are retrieved correctly,, i have the problem only when adding or editing symbol from the application..

here's my add php

```
<?php



// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['symbol']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$description = $_POST['description'];
$symbol = $_POST['symbol'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();
// mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); -> this needs to be removed

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO glossary(Symbol, Name, Description) VALUES('$symbol', '$name', '$description')");
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "glossary successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

and my db connect php

```
<?php

class DB_CONNECT {

// constructor
function __construct() {
    // connecting to database
    $this->connect();
}

// destructor
function __destruct() {
    // closing db connection
    $this->close();
}

/**
 * Function to connect with database
 */
function connect() {
    // import database connection variables
    require_once __DIR__ . '/db_config.php';

    // Connecting to mysql database
    $con = mysql_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD) or die(mysql_error());

    // Selecing database
    $db = mysql_select_db(DB_DATABASE) or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS =utf8;");
mysqli_query($link, "SET SESSION CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT =utf8;");
    // returing connection cursor
    return $con;
}

/**
 * Function to close db connection
 */
function close() {
    // closing db connection
    mysql_close();
}

}

?>
```

please someone help me with this .. thank you!

Comment: You're mixing `mysqli_` with `mysql_` functions; *why?* They just don't.

Comment: use header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

Comment: Then you have `or die(mysql_error()) or die(mysql_error());` ?! *Shoot a man while he's down, eh?*

Comment: also be sure your glossary table has columns set to utf8 collation, by the way

Comment: @Fred-ii- im sorry but can help correct my code cuz im not that familiar with mysql .. please ?

Comment: @RobP it is set to utf8

Answer (score 0):

to add **utf-8** in **php** you can use:

```
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
```

and in your code you are using: `mysql_query` and `mysqli_query` why this, use only one format and better use `mysqli_query` i.e. `mysqli` functions.

and better make proper corrections as @Fred-ii- has suggested.

Comment: Are you completely sure that that's all there's wrong with the OP's code? You probably may not have read my comments, or gone over the OP's code completely.

Comment: @Fred-ii- no i'm sorry i did n't see the code properly.

Comment: It's the first thing I look for whenever I spot `mysql_` functions being used ;-) Now, let's wait for the OP to respond, *cheers*

Comment: can yo help me please to make my code use mysqli only please ?

Answer (score 0):

Try running `SET NAMES 'utf8'` and `SET CHARSET 'utf8'` after connection to DB.

```
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
mysql_query("SET CHARSET 'utf8'");
```